# friend keyword for operator overloading

Tags: c++

I tried to write an simple example for the <<-operator-overloading.
Before, i've never used the keyword "friend". But it does not work without it. What is the mistake i did or why do i need the friend keyword here?

```
class rational{

public:
 rational(double num, double count)
    : n(num),c(count){}

 rational& operator+=(const rational& b){
    this->n+= b.n;
    this->c+= b.c;
    return *this;
 }

 friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const rational& obj)
 {
 std::cout << obj.n << "," << obj.c << std::endl;
 return os;
 }

private:
 double n;
 double c;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to stream objects whose internals are not accessible through their class' public interface, so the operator can't get at them. Then you have two choices: Either put a public member into the class which does the streaming

```
class T {
  public:
    void stream_to(std::ostream& os) const {os << obj.data_;}
  private:
    int data_;
};
```

and call that from the operator:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
   obj.stream_to(os);
   return os;
}
```

or make the operator a `friend`

```
class T {
  public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const T&);
  private:
    int data_;
};
```

so that it can access the class' private parts:

```
inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& obj)
{
   os << obj.data_;
   return os;
}
```

Comment: thanks you help me a lot!!! But is there not a os missing in the stream_to function? (std::ostream& os)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't make any mistake. The `friend` keyword gives your `operator<<()` implementation access to `private` (and `protected`, if you had any) members of your class.

Note that because it's a friend, `operator<<()` here is implicitly a free function and not a member function (if it were a member function, it could access `private` things already!). Because it's declared and defined only inside the class, it can only be found by argument-dependent lookup, but this is fine for `operator<<` and is a detail you don't have to worry about yet.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring and defining the operator inside the class, thus without `friend` it has an implicit first operand of type `rational`. You wouldn't have such problem if you had declared the operator outside the class, but then you wouldn't have access to n and c.

Comment: This answer seem to miss the question. The question is about the non-member function `operator<<()` that just happens to have been declared (and defined) inside the class definition as a `friend`, not the member function.

Comment: @Galik He said that he also tried the exact same code, just without the friend keyword, and asked why it didn't work that way. My answer was the explanation for that.

Comment: *she
Yes, Fabio thank you. I did not know, that i have to implement it as a free function.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of attention @Susliks